# request.getSession().setAttribute() & .getAttribute("reqid") thread safety

Tags: java, http, servlets

I have two forms, `a.jsp` & `b.jsp`.

When the first form is submitted, a Java servlet (ex. `a_servlet.java`) will be called which generates a `requestID` and redirects to `b.jsp`.

I need to pass the `requestID` generated from `a_servlet` to `b_servlet`.

I currently use the code below, but I have a feeling it is not thread safe, by that I mean, if a 2nd user fills `a.jsp` form before the 1st user finishes filling `b.jsp` form, there will be a `requestID` mix-up.

In `a_servlet.java`:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
//....
request.getSession().setAttribute("reqid", reqid);
//.... }
```

In `b_servlet.java`:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
//....
String reqid = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("reqid");
//.... }
```

Is there some solidation I need to do to make passing data between servlets thread-safe ?

Is there a better way? Maybe storing the `requestID` on the user side in a hidden HTML attribute in `b.jsp` comes to mind, but it doesn't feel right.

Comment: The users will have different sessions. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Are you saying my code is perfectly fine in it's current state ?

Comment: Yes... Sessions will be different for each user, so the attribute reqid will be safe to be passed and used.